# How do one distinguish different connections from the same machine to a socket, from eachother

Tags: c#, sockets

This is written in C#

Imagine this scenario.

I have a socket server service running on a computer. A lot of other processes on the same computer will be creating connections and sending requests to this server.

I want to collect these requests in a dictionary, and send them to an API over the internet, as i don't want to send them one at a time.

From the API i get a response for each of these requests in a dictionary, and here comes the question.

How do i return the proper responses to the right processes ?

I'm thinking there must be some way of identifying the process a request comes from, and then i could store that identifier together with the request, and then find that request again and use the identifier to send the proper response. But how :)

Thankyou beforehand for helping me :)

Comment: A socket the client connects with is bidirectional. You can keep it open until you get a response from the remote API, then send the response back via the same socket. You'll need to keep the socket object around in the dictionary, of course.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But the socket object in the server is only one object. How can i find the right connection to send the specific data to? I gather a lot of requests and get a bulk of responses to them via a rest service and then i want to return the proper request to the proper proces.

Comment: When you have a listening socket, you accept a connection; that connection object is unique for the connecting client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of:

SrcIP,
SrcPort,
DstIP,
DstPort

Is always globally unique.  No connection on any machine will ever be the same as any other connection.

So you can use this as your index if you're not framing a unique GUID into your protocol.